# How to duplicate a certain number of values and then change to another in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi guys I am trying to expand an existing dataset but I don't know exactly what I have to do.
For example I got this set of values

```
21
45
77
```

I need more observations, so I would like 4 observations of the same value and after the code should pass to the next value and generate another 4 observations
Something like this I mean:

```
21
21
21
21
45
45
45
45
77
77
77
77
```

Hope anyone can help me

Comment: please mention the type of the dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df.index.repeat(4)]
```

Or [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
pd.concat([df] * 4).sort_index()
```